# Configure post-hook if your subdirectory is mart and staging

Tags: dbt

I want to do different things depending if my sql file was in staging subdirectory or in mart subdirectory.

More specifically i want to grant different groups permissions depending on if its mart or staging

Currently i have different models that all have staging and mart directories in them, i want to modify my post-hook so it will do different things if file was from staging dict or not.

For example right now, in dbt_project.yml file i only have 1 post-hook in my models part:

```yaml
models:
  model_repo:
    +persist_docs: 
      relation: true
      columns: true
    +post-hook: 
      - "INSERT INTO {{ this }} values (NOW(),'post-hook')"
```

Is there a way i can have custom post-hook depending if it is from mart or staging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify different [post-hooks](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook) for staging and mart based in the [resource-path](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/resource-path):

```yaml
models:
  model_repo:
    staging:
      +post-hook: 
        - "-- post-hook for models in models/staging/*"
    mart:
      +post-hook: 
        - "-- post-hook for models in models/mart/*"
```

OR

To achieve a more dynamic behavior based on the model path, you can create a macro as [sugested by jtcohen6 in this comment](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/5442#issuecomment-1232023349):

```sql
{% macro grant_some_permission_macro() %}

  {% set fqn = model.fqn %}
  /*{# e.g. ['my_project', 'some_parent_dir', 'some_child_dir', 'part_a', 'part_b', 'some_model'] #}*/

  {% set layer = fqn[2] %}
  /*{# adjust to your subfolder level that represents the layer #}*/

  {% if layer = 'staging' %}
  GRANT STAGING_PERMISSION TO ...
  {% elif layer = 'mart' %}
  GRANT MART_PERMISSION TO ...
  {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Then use it:

```yaml
models:
  model_repo:
    +post-hook: 
      - "{{ grant_some_permission_macro() }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Since i have a lot of models, it is not wise to do it for each model separately, i was more thinking of having a placeholder for the model name (like *) then do mart and staging. Is that in any way possible? I cant find it in docs.

Comment: Also, i saw that in the newer versions there are grants, since i want to allow a certain group to have select permissions on mart and different one on staging, maybe that could be easier resolved that way.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your needs. In my example, you have only 2 post-hooks that will apply to all models in the respective folders. Are you want only one post-hook, but use the model path as a param to the query?

Comment: all my folders have mart and staging in them, so i want to make it dynamic. In your example it will only affect model_repo, i have model_repo_1, model_repo_2, etc. and all of them have mart and staging as subfolders in them.

Comment: @Djokovic I add another example using macro that allow a more dynamic behavior based on the model path.